# Checking for Constraint

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I need to write a SQL script to ensure that a constraint is existing.

If the constraint exists, I will be dropping the constraint.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Schema.constraintname') IS NOT NULL
   ALTER TABLE Schema.foo DROP constarintname
```

You need `Schema.constraintname` to correctly resolve schema. You could have 2 `PK_foo` objects if you have tables `this.foo` and `that.foo`